# CSS: displaying tables next to each other if there is space

Tags: html, css

I don't understand the positions yet so i'm struggling with this.
The main idea is, that I have tables next to each other and when it doesn't fit next to each other it goes beneath the other table and so on.
It wil be around 2 to 8 tables.

I have some code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/wewk586z

Here is my CSS with this table (also provided in the jsfiddle)

```
#position1 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want exatly?

Comment: @ehsan The code you provided was what I was looking for thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrap table in div that have `tab` class :

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .tab {
  float: left;
 }
```

```html
<div class="tab" id="position1">
<table id="border">
  <caption>Medewerker 1</caption>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Dag 1</th>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Dag 2</th>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Dag 3</th>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Dag 4</th>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Dag 5</th>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="tab">
<table id="border">
  <caption>Medewerker 2</caption>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Dag 1</th>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Dag 2</th>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Dag 3</th>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Dag 4</th>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Dag 5</th>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="tab">
<table id="border">
  <caption>Medewerker 3</caption>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Dag 1</th>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Dag 2</th>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Dag 3</th>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Dag 4</th>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Dag 5</th>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>


<div class="tab">
<table id="border">
  <caption>Medewerker 3</caption>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Dag 1</th>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Dag 2</th>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
  </tr>
 
</table>
</div>

<div class="tab">
<table id="border">
  <caption>Medewerker 4</caption>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Dag 1</th>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Dag 2</th>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
  </tr>
 
</table>
</div>

<div class="tab">
<table id="border">
  <caption>Medewerker 5</caption>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Dag 1</th>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Dag 2</th>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
      <td>Opdracht: 12-654 <br>
          Kritische Datum: 22-05-2017</td>
  </tr>
 
</table>
</div>
```

Note: Use Full Page for better result.

Answer (score 1):

try setting `width: 50%` and then adding breakpoints to make them 100% when they don't fit anymore, for example:

```
#position1 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

@media screen and max(width: 800px){
    #position1{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I want, It needs to go underneath the other table

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS into the following:

```
table {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything, it just puts them beneath each other